# Angular 2 - Unable to display rows of data in tabular column format

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Angular. I am trying to display rows of data in a tabular column format. But each field in a row is displayed as row. I want each field in a row to be displayed next to each other as different columns in a single row. Below is my HTML code:

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2 class="page-header">Add Contact</h2>
  <form (submit)="addContact()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.first_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.last_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.phone}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is how the data is displayed currently]

Comment: look at `ng template`

Comment: Change from `col-md-3` to `col-xs-3` or `col-sm-3`. I'm guessing your viewport is larger than `md`, so it falls back to full width

Comment: im assuming your using bootstrap. you need to wrap the col-md-3 divs in a div with a class of "row" so then you can use the grid system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bootstrap issue. Try wrapping your col-md-3 divs in a row.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.first_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.last_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      {{contact.phone}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
      <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this codepen, you can visualize it: https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/rrYzaV

Comment: Wrapping the col-md-3 divs in a row fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change from col-md-3 to col-xs-3 or col-sm-3. I'm guessing your viewport is larger than md, so it falls back to full width.

Try running the snippet below

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <h2 class="page-header">Add Contact</h2>
  <form (submit)="addContact()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping the col-md-3 divs in a row fixed the problem. Thanks to @dream_cap answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, use [Angular Flex](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) for arranging your `<div>`s as per your requirement. Its pretty simple once your know how to use Angular Flex([refer](http://www.dzurico.com/angular-flex-layout/)).